# Customized twitter button with pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

This is the code for my Twitter button that works:

```
var tweeturl = 'http://twitter.com/share?url=' + encodeURI(window.location) +'&via=MyTwitterUserName&text=The editable text I want to include automatically in the tweet';

// Place the text on the page. Change body to wherever you want the button placed. 
$('div[data-role="footer"] > div').append('<a id="mycustomtwitterbutton" href=" ' + tweeturl + ' "><img src="/Content/images/share_twitter.jpg"></a>')
```

I've a simple question.

I would like to open the link as a pop-up dialog and not in a new page and that when I click on "OK" to confirm the tweet of the link, it returns in my application.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do without more code, but the javascript version of the pop-up is below.

```
var actwin=window.open(location,'mywindow',
'width=706,height=630,status=no,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes');
actwin.focus();
```

This is some javascript code for a confirmation message.

```
var x=window.confirm("Question?");
if (x){
 ///code
}
else{}
```